# Regex to check for a markdown link at point

Tags: regular-expressions

I am trying to develop a regex to check if points is within a GitHub markdown link to a wiki page, and then extract that page name. For example

```
some text [link_name](https://github.com/user/wiki/Tool-info) more text
```

If point is between the `[` and the `)` and the user clicks a keyboard shortcut, I would like to extract the name of the wiki page, namely `Tool-info`..

Here is what I have:

```el
(defun test-wiki ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((name nil) (m-beginning nil))
    (save-excursion
      (if (char-equal (char-after) ?\[)
          (setq m-beginning t)
        (when (looking-back "\\[[^)]*?" (line-beginning-position))
          (setq m-beginning t)
          (goto-char (match-beginning 0))))
      (when m-beginning
        (when (looking-at "\\[[\\w]+?\\](\\([:/.\\w]+?\\))")
          (setq name (match-string 1)))))
    (if name
        (message name)
      (message "No match"))))
```

Currently, this gives message `"No match"` in all cases..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `\w` inside a character class in Emacs, instead you can use:

```el
(when (looking-at "\\[\\w+?\\](\\([-:/.[:alnum:]]+?\\))")
```